# Really slow and simple query, how to increase speed?

Tags: mysql

My query:

```
(
    SELECT
        V.ID AS V_ID, 
        MAX(V_A.ID) AS MAX_V_A_ID 
    FROM V 
    INNER JOIN V_A on V_A.V_ID = V.ID 
    GROUP BY V.ID 
)
```

With big data set, this query is extremely slow, exist any possibility to improve it ?

Comment: Add indexes to the columns used in the select?

Comment: Indexres on this key are created

Comment: yes, these two tables have index on primary key (id)

Comment: Is `V_A.V_ID` (not `ID`) and `V.ID` both indexes?

Comment: this query is only part of big query, but this small quey has 15% of time all query

Comment: If v.id AND v_a.v_id are both indexed then there's not much you can do. One must be a huge table.

Comment: yes, all id have indexes... ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to add index on **v.id** and **v_a.v_id**

it should improve it a lot

if it didn't help use explain plan... or try to think about partitioning :)